# Error in Android Studio: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or collection of it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on a simple note application in Android Studio and have set up a Room database with entities, DAO, and the database class. However, when trying to compile my code, I received the following error message: "**error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it. kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Long> $completion);**"

Here is the NotesDao code:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface NotesDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertNote(note: Notes): Long

    @Update
    suspend fun updateNote(note: Notes): Int

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteNote(note: Notes): Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes_data_table")
    fun getAllNotes(): Flow<List<Notes>>
}
```

Here is the Notes entity:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "notes_data_table")
data class Notes(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Int? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_title")
    val title:String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "note_body")
    val body:String
)
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.5.1"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    //coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1'

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    //ssp, sdp
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:<version>'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

This issue has been asked before by others, and they solved it by updating their Kotlin and/or Room versions. However, I am currently using the latest versions and still encountering the error. I have experimented with downgrading versions as suggested in past threads, but the error persists.

Edit:included my database class

```
@Database(entities = [Notes::class], version = 1)
abstract class NotesDB : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val notesDAO: NotesDao
 
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: NotesDB? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): NotesDB {
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        NotesDB::class.java,
                        "notes_data_database"
                    ).build()
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So which line in the code you've shown actually generates that error?

Comment: I went to project error and it shows its NotesDao.java which are auto generated
  `@androidx.room.Insert(onConflict = 1)
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    public abstract java.lang.Object insertNote(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
    com.wise.calculator.Notes notes, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Long> $completion);`



 NotesDao.java:11: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.

Comment: Sounds to me like whatever's generating the Dao code doesn't know how to handle `suspend` functions.

Comment: try removing the suspend keyword

Comment: Hey @wise394 can you please check your database class, have you created a table using the same name or not? because this type of error show if the database makes time not to create a table using the same name.  
Can you please verify this first?

Comment: @mujjuraja I added my database class on the main post, I'm not entirely sure as I used a tutorial as reference to make my database class

Comment: Edit your question to Include the `@Database` annotation. It is the `entities=` parameter that defines the Entities to be considered. i.e. you should something along the lines of `@Database(entities = [Notes::class] .... )` *where .... represents the other values*. You should not have NotesDao::class as an entity.

Comment: @MikeT sorry i I forgot to add the `@database ` anotation on my question but I have it in my code and it's still not working.`@Database(entities = [Notes::class], version = 1)`  this is my database anotation

Comment: If you would like I can give you my code as an answer. My notes pad on Play Store uses room and it’s almost to 1,000 downloads. Your code is almost an exact replica in base form. I can post that code in a little while if you need it still

Comment: @CampNerd yes pls I really appreciate that, I'm trying to fix this problem since yesterday and did alot of experimenting but I'm still stuck

Comment: @wise394 hey I have not forgotten about you.. it got busy here I forgot it was fathers day weekend so I have not been able to post it yet. I will post it today

Comment: @wise394 do you have a rough idea of how you want it to look, work and feel.. as I said before I have a notes app called.. Nexus Notes ... My developer account is NerdSpace Software on Play store. Take a look at it it was built in room. Room is awesome until you have to move to another phone and it doesn't back up even with full backup unless I am doing something wrong that why I am moving from room to firebase